# Transformer load

Tags: transformer, three-phase, power-engineering, single-phase, distribution-network

I have 50 kVA delta-wye transformer with 3 single phases secondary (line-neutral) delivered to 3 houses, So if one of the 3 houses drown more power would that affect another 2 houses, or each phase can only handle certain amount of power separately?

Comment: Have you ever heard of "imbalance" or "unbalanced load"?

Comment: _"3 single phases secondary (line-neutral)"_ More commonly known as three phase Y (or wye, depending on country).